# Meaning of ''of'' at the start of a sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

Recently I have read a headline on a newspaper stating ''Of Dragons and Dynasties''. It described the country Bhutan, but my question is how to perceive this sentence in full?

Comment: Newspaper headlines, just like other titles, don't need to be full sentences.

Comment: Common enough in book or story titles, too. E.g. "Of Men and Ships" - it's a book about those things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titles do not have to be complete sentences, and usually are consistently *incomplete* in ways that create a sense of dramatic expectation, in order to encourage you to read the rest.

In this example, "of" means "relating to", or "belonging to".  The ambiguity in the title raises the question of *how* the article will relate to "dragons" and "dynasties".  To get the answer, of course, you have to read the article.

As a related example is the famous short novel ["Of Mice and Men"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Of_Mice_and_Men) by John Steinbeck, required reading in many U.S. high schools.   The novel suggests it will discuss both "mice" and "men", but it is not clear how they relate, especially in the context of Depression-era farm laborers.   To get the answer, you have to read the novel.

Side note:  The title of the novel is actually taken from Robert Burns' poem "To a Mouse", which reads:

> The best laid schemes o' mice an' men
>   Gang aft agley".
>
> (= The best laid schemes of mice and men / Often go awry.)

If you recognize the literary reference, you will anticipate the story is about a plan with good intentions that does not work out according to the planners' hopes.

Also note that (assuming [this is the article](https://www.thedailystar.net/star-weekend/travelogue/news/dragons-and-dynasties-bhutan-uncovered-1734913)) the text actually talks about neither dragons nor dynasties.  So the title is a kind of "misleading promise" that suggests some fantastical mystery, but ends up mostly talking about the mundane.